# Describing sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to describe in words the following sets:

1. $A:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x>0, y\leq 1\}$

   $A$ is the set of all pointgs where the first coordinate is positiv and the second one is less or equal to $1$.

   Is thisdescription enough or can we say also something else?
2. $C:=\mathbb{N}\times \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid 0\leq x\leq 2\}$

   $C$ is the cartesian product of the natural number and the interval $[0,2]$. What else can we say here?

$$$$

I want to give also the corresponding set fo the following:

[image]

It is $\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x \leq 2, 1\leq y\leq 3\}$, right? But how could we justify that it is like that?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your descriptions of 1 and 2. And there's nothing to justify; your set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:0\le x\le 2,1\le y\le 3\}$ is the set of points described by the square in the image.

Comment: Ah ok! The set $A$ describes an infinite parallelogram, or not? What does $C$ describe? @palmpo

Comment: Maybe $C$ is the set of infinity many vertical lines of length 2? Or the other way around, for each $x\in[0,2]$, infinity many horizontal dots? I think most would simply write $C=\mathbb{N}\times[0,2]$ and that'd be it, without a description.

Comment: The last one is [0,2]×[1,3].

Comment: Ah ok! But how does the graph of $C$ look like? @palmpo

Comment: $[0,2]\times [1,3]$ is equivalent to $\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x \leq 2, 1\leq y\leq 3\}$, isn't it? @WilliamElliot

Comment: @MaryStar.  C is a bunch of parallel line segements.  No, they are not equivalent, they're equal.